# Usage of `boost::phoenix::static_cast_` mixed with standard library

Tags: c++, boost, std, boost-phoenix

**It is a Phoenix v3 bug. It compiles with Phoenix v2 just fine.
I did bug report. 
 I will mark this question as resolved in 2 days. Thank you all.**

I am trying to make a short lamba with phoenix, but I get bunch of compile errors. Here is the code.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> data;
using boost::phoenix::arg_names::_1;
using boost::phoenix::static_cast_;
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << std::hex;
//Doesn't compile
std::for_each(data.begin(),data.end(), oss <<  static_cast_<unsigned int>(_1) );
//Compiles
std::for_each(data.begin(),data.end(), oss << _1 );
```

Now I get the following compile error from GCC 4.6.1:
`/usr/include/boost/utility/result_of.hpp:-1: In instantiation of ‘boost::detail::result_of_nested_result<boost::phoenix::static_cast_eval, boost::phoenix::static_cast_eval(boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::detail::target<unsigned char> >, 0l>&, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<1> >, 0l> >&, boost::phoenix::vector2<boost::phoenix::vector2<const boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tag::shift_left, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<std::basic_ostringstream<char>&>, 0l> >, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::tag::static_cast_, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::detail::target<unsigned char> >, 0l>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<1> >, 0l> > >, 2l> > >, 2l> >*, unsigned char&>&, const boost::phoenix::default_actions&>)>’:`

`/usr/include/boost/phoenix/object/static_cast.hpp:29: error: declaration of ‘struct boost::phoenix::static_cast_eval::result<boost::phoenix::static_cast_eval(boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::detail::target<unsigned char> >, 0l>&, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<1> >, 0l> >&, boost::phoenix::vector2<boost::phoenix::vector2<const boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tag::shift_left, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<std::basic_ostringstream<char>&>, 0l> >, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::tag::static_cast_, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::detail::target<unsigned char> >, 0l>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<1> >, 0l> > >, 2l> > >, 2l> >*, unsigned char&>&, const boost::phoenix::default_actions&>)>’`

`/usr/include/boost/phoenix/core/detail/preprocessed/call_10.hpp:65: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct boost::result_of<boost::phoenix::static_cast_eval(boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::detail::target<unsigned char> >, 0l>&, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<1> >, 0l> >&, boost::phoenix::vector2<boost::phoenix::vector2<const boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tag::shift_left, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<std::basic_ostringstream<char>&>, 0l> >, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::phoenix::tag::static_cast_, boost::proto::argsns_::list2<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::detail::target<unsigned char> >, 0l>, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::proto::exprns_::basic_expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::phoenix::argument<1> >, 0l> > >, 2l> > >, 2l> >*, unsigned char&>&, const boost::phoenix::default_actions&>)>’`

Comment: Can you post a link to the bug report please?

Comment: For future reference, the bug report is probably this one, marked as fixed: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6040

Answer (score 0):

Both compiles here on both GCC & MSVC, if I would have a stab at it I would guess that the offender is:

```
using boost::phoenix::arg_names::_1;
```

There's other placeholders with the very same name, some imported to the global scope ( I believe the one boost::bind uses is in the global scope for example ). The last error in particular hints at this, as it would seem a type that is required to be a meta function isn't is used somewhere.

Comment: I got rid of this `using` clause, and changed the algorithm clause to:
`std::for_each(data.begin(),data.end(), oss << static_cast_<unsigned int>(boost::phoenix::arg_names::_1) );`

I get the same errors.
Here (http://ideone.com/D6SyS), it compiles just fine. On ideone.com
GCC is 4.3.4, and Boost is 1.39. Mine are GCC 4.6.1 and Boost 1.47.
They inroduced new version of phoenix with 1.47 called v3, maybe this is the problem. Thank you for your reply @Ylisar.